# How to get RxJS Observable events in zero time?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm collecting all the events of an Observable to a `data` array:

```js
const obs$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .take(4);

let data = [];
const start = performance.now();

obs$.subscribe(
  value => {
    data.push({
      time: performance.now() - start,
      data: value
    });
  },
  () => {},
  () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.2.0/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to "foresee the future" and get the same `data` array **without waiting 2 seconds**?

To clarify, I'm trying to find a way to wrap somehow a given Observable (`obs$` in the example above) with a custom timer/scheduler so I could get the events immediately.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) emits a sequence of integers with the specified interval between them. If you want the sequence of integers to be emitted immediately, you can use [`range`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-range) instead.

Comment: @cartant I'm trying to find a way to wrap somehow a given Observable (`obs$` in the example above) with a custom timer/scheduler so I could get the events immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an instance of the [`VirtualTimeScheduler`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.ts) and can specify it in the call to `interval`.

If you then call `flush` on the scheduler after subscribing, the events will be emitted immediately:

```js
const scheduler = new Rx.VirtualTimeScheduler();

const obs$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(500, scheduler)
  .take(4);

let data = [];
const start = scheduler.now();

obs$.subscribe(
  value => {
    data.push({
      time: scheduler.now() - start,
      data: value
    });
  },
  () => {},
  () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
);

scheduler.flush();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.2.0/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. The only question is: Is it possible to take an existing Observable and inject a scheduler to it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There are [`observeOn`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-observeOn) and [`subscribeOn`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribeOn) operators, but they won't change the source observable's scheduler.