# Why is jest.useFakeTimers not working with RxJs Observable delay

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs, asynctest

I'm wondering why `jest.useFakeTimers` is working with `setTimeout` but not with the delay operator of RxJs:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs';

describe('timers', () => {
    it('should resolve setTimeout synchronously', () => {
        const spy = jest.fn();
        setTimeout(spy, 20);
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        jest.runTimersToTime(20);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
    it('should resolve setInterval synchronously', () => {
        const spy = jest.fn();
        setInterval(spy, 20);
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        jest.runTimersToTime(20);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        jest.runTimersToTime(20);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
    it('should work with observables', () => {
        const delay$ = Observable.of(true).delay(20);
        const spy = jest.fn();
        delay$.subscribe(spy);
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        jest.runTimersToTime(2000);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

[image]

FYI: using 20 or 2000 as an argument for `jest.runTimersToTime` makes no difference.
Using `jest.runAllTimers()` makes the test past

Answer (score 13):

The `delay` operator does not work with Jest's fake timers because the `delay` operator's implementation uses its scheduler's concept of time - which is unrelated to Jest's concept of fake time.

The source is [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/delay.ts#L91-L93):

```
while (queue.length > 0 && (queue[0].time - scheduler.now()) <= 0) {
  queue.shift().notification.observe(destination);
}
```

The current (non-fake) time is assigned to notifications when they are created and the current time is what the scheduler's `now` method returns. When Jest's fake timers are used, an insufficient amount of actual (non-fake) time will have elapsed and the notifications will remain in the queue.

To write RxJS tests using fake or virtual time, you can use the `VirtualTimeScheduler`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43108109/6680611). Or you can use the `TestScheduler` and [marble tests](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md).

Comment: If you decide to use marble tests, you might find [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-marble-testing-rtfm-a9a6cd3db758) helpful.

Comment: you can also mock `delay` function to replace the implementation with a combination of `delayWhen` and `timer` which does not suffers from this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478886/5251198