# How to test timer-based RxJS observables in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm moderately new to RxJS and very new to unit testing with Jest and I've run into a pretty confusing problem when trying to test some mocked-up RxJS observables.

In order to mimic a data stream, I created an Observable in a test `spec.js` file like this:

```
var Rx = require("rx");

var source = Rx.Observable.interval(500).take(10);

source.subscribe(
    function(x){ console.log(x) },
    function(e){ console.log(e) },
    function(){ console.log('completed') }
  );
```

Although this logs correctly when just ran as a node script, it doesn't log anything when ran through `npm test`. The `Observable.delay` and `setTimeout`  functions don't appear to work as well.

Comment: Read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264151/1071200) and the answers that it links to.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

```
var Rx = require("rx");

describe("Interval Test", () => {
  const source = Rx.Observable.interval(100);
  let count = 0;
  source.subscribe(
  x => count++,
  e => console.log("error: ", e),
  () => console.log("complete"));

  it("run for 1 second", done => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('one second passed');
      expect(count).toBe(10);
      done();
    }, 1010)
  });
});
```

It seems like I needed to put a timeOut in my `it` test function in order for this async observable to be able to execute. Also really important was the `done()` call in order to prevent the time from running indefinitely.

Note: Alternately, if you want to use Jest's fake time to control timing manually, that seems to work as well. I find that I did not need to use the VirtualTimeScheduler.

```
jest.useFakeTimers();    
var Rx = require("rx");

var source = Rx.Observable.interval(500).take(10);

source.subscribe(
    function(x){ console.log(x) },
    function(e){ console.log(e) },
    function(){ console.log('completed') }
  );
jest.runAllTimers();
```